# Поворот вектора вокруг другого

Tags: математика, разработка-игр, графика, геометрия, вектор

Я пишу простую игру с графикой(мячик отскакивает от границ окна и от линий, который пользователь строит сам). Мне нужно что бы мячик отталкивался от границ и менял направление в зависимости от угла падения на прямую(угол падения, равен углу отражения другими словами). v1 = (vx, vy) - вектор скорости мячика, v2 = (y2-y1, x1-x2) - вектор перпендикулярный прямой, с которой он столкнулся (x1, x2, y1, y2 - это две точки, по которым строится прямая). Как мне повернуть вектор v1 вокруг v2, чтобы угол падения был равен углу отражения? (надеюсь понятно объяснил). Был бы рад если бы кто-нибудь помог мне найти ответ на этот вопрос. Уже не первую неделю мучаюсь(

Comment: Уж за "не первую неделю" уже можно было бы ознакомиться с курсом геометрии, где есть ответ не только на этот, но и на многие другие вопросы.

Comment: @Эникейщик скажите пожалуйста насколько глубоко надо знать геометрию чтобы решать такие задачи ?

Comment: @Leks первого года школьного курса более чем достаточно.

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо что ответили на вопрос

Comment: @Leks тут все просто на самом деле, достаточно только нарисовать всю эту конструкцию (две прямых - горизонталь и на которую падает луч, луч падения, луч отражения).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть вектор направления `dir = V1`, а единичная нормаль к поверхности, от которой происходит отражение `N = V2.normalized()`

Вектор направления можно разложить на компоненты тангенциальный и нормальный к поверхности. Первый остаётся неизменным, второй инвертируется

Вектор направления после отражения с использованием скалярного произведения:

```
dot = dir.x * n.x + dir.y * n.y

newdir.x = dir.x - 2 * dot * n.x
newdir.y = dir.y - 2 * dot * n.y
```